# Can't display website of the container from host

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I want to display the website of my apache/php container from host (Windows 10).
It is'nt works and I don't find why..

**From the browser's host**

- OK : It displays MailDev through localhost:1080
- NOT OK : It can't display my procject website through localhost

  The browser return : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

**Inside the Docker's container "WEB"**

I tried curl localhost in the container and returns me the html code of the website.

**Docker-compose file**
Here is my docker-compose file and it works fine for all my other projects.

```
---
web:
    image: "rifton007/web:php7.1a"
    volumes:
        - "./:/var/www/html"
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    links:
        - mail
mail:
    image: djfarrelly/maildev
    ports:
        - "1080:80"
        - "1025:25"
```

Thank you,

Comment: I have same problem with another docker-compose for NodeJs developpements. Two services : NodeJS and MongoDB. For MongoDB no problems, I access it from Windows. On NodeJS, I have installed two package for trying : AdonisJS and Express, the both listen the port 3000. When I launch server Express, no problem. When I launch Adonis server, ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I don't understand the problem. Thanks,

Comment: Create a overlay network bridge and run your containers on them